# How to start a new activity after a user clicked on a madvertise banner?

Tags: android

I'm creating a new Android App, but I have a problem unable to solve.

I need after user clicked madvertise banner and return from browser to my app, finish the activity where the user launched the click and start a new one. The function that I used for Admob was OnDissmissScreen();, is there a workarround to solve like this?

Thanks.

Best regards;

Answer (score 0):

I add an onClickHandler in Madvertise SDK as explaind  Johannes Borchardt in his [blog](http://droid-blog.net/2012/02/04/android-income-report-9-january-12/) (look answer from him to Ivan)

The problem that my code does not work in a secondary activitiy but works on the main Window (when the App start)

```
       mMadView2.setMadvertiseViewCallbackListener(new MadvertiseViewCallbackListener() {
        public void onError(Exception exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onIllegalHttpStatusCode(int statusCode,
                String message) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



        public void onLoaded(boolean succeed, MadvertiseView madView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void onAdClicked() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(click.this, mainWindow.class);
            //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
            startActivity(intent);     
            finish();     
        }

    });
```